# For any real number $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there is a rational sequence converging to that point

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

I am having trouble seeing this. How can we be certain that a rational sequence will converge to a real number?

Comment: Define real number first.

Comment: The definition we gave used in class is:  real numbers are objects with infinite decimal expansion

Comment: That is an uncommon definition. However workable. Consider the decimal expansion of a real number and truncating it at $n$ digits.

Comment: By adding smaller and smaller fractions we can get to within any $\epsilon > 0$ of a real number. That is basically what convergence means.

Comment: @Zachary what would be the most common definition of a real number?

Comment: Typically we define real numbers through Cauchy sequences or Dedikind cuts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose rationals $a_1,b_1$ such that $a_1 < a < b_1$. Now, consider $t_1 = (a_1+b_1)/2$. If $a < t_1$, define $a_2 = a_1$ and $b_2 = t_1$. Otherwise set $a_2 = t_1$ and $b_2 = b_1$. Now go on this way. This will define you a sequence of rationals that converges to $a$.

Comment: True, and worth a vote, but there are a few details still in the proof.

Comment: Sure. But I don't like to give full solutions because it is my opinion that the OP should learn from it. And the best way to learn is figuring out stuff by yourself.